# Is it appropriate to edit own post to get more attention

Tags: discussion

I am allowed to edit my own posts maximum of 5 in a day. But want to increase my knowledge about the appropriate reason for it.

Are the following scenarios OK?

1. Edit a question which is not answered.
2. Edit a question which is answered and I have accepted it.
3. Edit an answer which is not accepted.
4. Edit an answer which is accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 and 4 can be a problem if you are significantly changing something. Editing for the sole reason to get more attention wouldn't be acceptable in my opinion, unless it is to clarify or add more context which would lead to a potential answer. Otherwise, consider opening a bounty on your question.

Comment: That gives me a good idea about the working of the community site. Cheers..